# Single Month Digit Date Format issue in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

Am getting the below issue when am using 'mon-d-yyyy' to convert date to char, as i need a single day digit for values from 1 to 9 days in a month.

When i use the 'mon-d-yyyy' format, am losing out on 5 days and getting a wrong date. Any help on this would be great.

```
select to_char(sysdate-22,'mon-d-yyyy') from dual;--aug-2-2017

select to_char(sysdate-22,'mon-dd-yyyy') from dual;--aug-07-2017

select sysdate-22 from dual;--07-AUG-17 11.06.43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to piece together the date output you want:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(sysdate-22, 'mon-') ||
    TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TO_CHAR(sysdate-22, 'dd-')) ||
    TO_CHAR(sysdate-22, 'yyyy')
FROM dual;
```

The middle term involving `TRIM` strips off the leading zeroes, if present, from the date.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Maybe a bit overkill. Using `fm` is much simpler.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The other answer wasn't giving a single digit day when I tested it.  Perhaps you should post something.

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle date formats, `d` gets the day of week. The `2` in your output means `monday`, not august the 2nd.

Try using `Fill Mode` as [Format Model Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216)

```
select to_char(sysdate-22,'mon-fmdd-yyyy') from dual;
```

Comment: Just a note, `fm` acts as a switch. Most likely it does not apply but year is also truncated, e.g.`to_char(sysdate-365*2000,'mon-fmdd-yyyy')` gives `dec-30-18`. Use `to_char(sysdate-22,'mon-fmdd-fmyyyy')` in order to get full year (if applicable).

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SQL>SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('29-AUG-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') - 22,'"WEEKDAY :"D, MON-FMDD-YYYY') "Before22Days" FROM DUAL;
```

> D- Gives you a numeric weekday(2nd weekday in a week) on AUG-07-2017.
>   DD-Gives a Numeric Month Day i.e,07th
>   FMDD-Gives 7th

```
Before22Days
----------------------
WEEKDAY :2, AUG-7-2017
```